# iphone safari browser html alignment problem

Tags: iphone, css, safari

In the following URl, the bottom right corner text is not aligned to the right property in iphone safari browser.
[link](http://www.pandamama.com/tsseafood1/home.php)

But it is aligned properly in safari browsers in pc, even in other browsers (e.g. ie, firefox) are also ok.

The code is listed below:

```
<div id="footer">
    <br />
    <div style="float: left; letter-spacing: 3px;  font-family: PMingLiU; font-size:18px;">
        &#35531;&#35242;&#33256;&#26412;&#24215;&#36984;&#36092; &#39321;&#28207;&#24503;&#36628;&#36947;&#35199;94&#34399;
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; letter-spacing: 3px;  font-family: PMingLiU; font-size:18px;">現購物滿港幣3800元可享專人送貨服務 查詢電話:25483136</div>
    <br /><br />
   <div style="float: right; letter-spacing: 2px;  font-family: PMingLiU; font-size:16px;">只限於香港九龍港鑯沿線</div>  
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Do you have any idea on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a font issue with Mobile Safari. The numbers on Mobile Safari come out looking Times-ish whereas on normal Safari they look Helvetica-ish and the spacing is a little different in the numbers. A bit of experimentation yields a somewhat odd workaround, wrapping the numbers in a `<span>` moves them to the right side (but moves the extra space to the right of the colon):

```
<div style="float: right; letter-spacing: 3px;  font-family: PMingLiU; font-size:18px;">現購物滿港幣3800元可享專人送貨服務 查詢電話:<span>25483136</span></div>
```

And an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AydWp/4/embedded/result/

Not really a solution but possibly an improvement.